# gpio pin is not exported in linux

Tags: interrupt, gpio

I have tried the following to export the gpio in linux userspace:

- In kernel config,

  ```
  Device Drivers --->
        --- GPIO Support
              [*] /sys/class/gpio/... (sysfs interface)
  ```
- GPIO=9

  ```
  echo $GPIO >/sys/class/gpio/export
  ```
- `used gpio_export(9)` in my code
- tried to export all the gpio. But no gpio is exported.

What am I missing in exporting gpio pins in sysfs..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you requested for the GPIO via "gpio_request"? A call to gpio_export should export the GPIO to the sysfs for control.